# laravel Remote connection [] not defined issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5 I configured two remote servers in `config/remote.php`and I used it for more than a year. When I added a third server now it always triggered  this error

> "laravel Remote connection [servername] not defined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question because I can't find the correct answer anywhere and I spent few hours to fix it. I believe this may help others or help myself in future.

After trying everything, I suspected that the configuration is not served from config/remote.php so i renamed config/remote.php to config/remote.php1 now also both servers added last year worked without issue so i searched my app directory

`grep -iRl "myoldservername.com"`

it returned with

```
bootstrap/cache/config.php
config/remote.php1
config/remote.php.save
```

I confirmed that the remote server configuration has been served from cached config file.
I renamed config/remote.php1 back to config/remote.php again and executed

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Now the new and old servers worked fine.